# How to unsqueezed the y-axis in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a this script which try to plot the x and y-axis:

```js
var margin = {top: 100, right: 100, bottom: 100, left: 100},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["apple", "orange", "banana"])
    .rangePoints([0, width]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .call(xAxis);


var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["1", "2", "3"])
    .rangePoints([0, 3]);


var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);
```

```css
.axis text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see upon running the code the y-axis is squeezed down. How can I unsqueezed it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set your y range correctly

```
var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["1", "2", "3"])
    .rangePoints([height, 0]);
```

---

From the documentation (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#ordinal_rangePoints),

> # ordinal.rangePoints(interval[, padding])
>
> Sets the output range from the specified continuous interval. The
>   array interval contains two elements representing the minimum and
>   maximum numeric value. This interval is subdivided into n
>   evenly-spaced points, where n is the number of (unique) values in the
>   input domain.

You input domain has 3 values which you want to space out over the height of the chart.

---

**Stack Snippet**

You might also want to translate your x axis to the bottom (if not, just revert the translate on the x axis)

```js
var margin = {top: 100, right: 100, bottom: 100, left: 100},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["apple", "orange", "banana"])
    .rangePoints([0, width]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .call(xAxis)
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + height + ")");;


var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["1", "2", "3"])
    .rangePoints([height, 0]);


var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);
```

```css
.axis text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
```